# Approximation of $|x|^p$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a,b$ be reals and $1\leq p$.

How do I prove that there exists $O(\epsilon)$ such that $|a+b|^p - |a|^p \leq \epsilon |a|^p + O(\epsilon) |b|^p$ for a given $\epsilon >0$? Direct taylor expansion cannot handle because $O(\epsilon)$ would then depend on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What does $\epsilon$ have to do with anything?

Comment: My question is, for a given $\epsilon>0$, whether there exists a function $O(\epsilon)$ such that $|a+b|^p - |a|^p \leq \epsilon |a|^p+ O(\epsilon)|b|^p$. It does do something.. I'm trying to use this to prove this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828959/do-weakly-convergence-and-convervence-a-e-imply-the-following

Comment: I see, I missed the $\epsilon$ in front of the $|a|^p$.

Comment: If that's your question, then you should state the question that way. Otherwise this $\epsilon$ just comes out of nowhere.

Comment: @zhw. I see. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Take $p=2$, $a={1 \over \epsilon}, b = 1$ and substitute into the equation, bringing the $ \epsilon |a|^2$ term to the left hand side.

Then we want to show $({1 \over \epsilon} + 1)^2 -(1+\epsilon){1 \over \epsilon^2}  \le f(\epsilon)$, where $f $ is $O(\epsilon)$.

The left hand side is $1+ {1 \over \epsilon }$, hence no such $f$ can exist.